# Posición del mouse dentro de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un *DataGridView* con el evento *CellMouseMove*, deseo saber la posición del *mouse* cuando pase dentro de la celda para abrir un control de usuario. Esto es lo que tengo:

```
ResumenDatosReserva ResumenDatosReserva = new ResumenDatosReserva();
                    int corx = e.X;
                    int cory = e.Y;
                    Point point = new Point(corx,cory);
                    ResumenDatosReserva.Location = point;
                    this.dgvPrestamos.Controls.Add(ResumenDatosReserva);
                    ResumenDatosReserva.BringToFront();
```

Lo que sucede es que no me da las posiciones correctas del *mouse*, y si lo intento con la propiedad *MousePosition* igual me da la posición del *mouse* errónea.

Adjunto un ejemplo:
[image: Ejemplo error]

Tenemos unas coordenadas en la parte superior izquierda, la primera son las coordenadas del control y la segunda son las coordenadas del Mouse, son las mismas pero si vemos en la ubicación real del Mouse (el punto rojo) y el control no es lo mismo, ya que el control está mas abajo.

Comment: te da incorrectas?? basadas en que point?? no sera que te da la posicion absoluta sobre el form?? o te da la posicion absoluta sobre el control?

Comment: @gbianchi Ya lo intenté de las dos maneras, lo intenté basándome en el control _DataGridView_ y en el _form_ y aún así (de las dos maneras) me da de manera incorrecta  las coordenadas.

Comment: @gbianchi Te adjunto este [Pantallazo] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzb0sDggYC2cZDNBMEh6NjhFck0) para que observes que es el error, si observamos en la parte superior izquierda vemos dos coordenadas, en el primer label están las coordenadas del control y en el segundo las del Mouse, son las mismas pero si vemos en la imagen el mouse es el punto rojo y el control se encuentra más abajo.

Comment: @gbianchi Ya lo hice

Comment: Probe creando una grilla, y cada vez que entro a una celda, me devuelve un punto distinto.. tal vez tengas otro problema? podes mostrar mas codigo o compartir un [mcve] donde reproduzcas el error?

Comment: @gbianchi Subo mi código a la pregunta? o a donde?

Comment: Si la solucion que te dieron no sirve, mira el link que te pase, y crea un ejemplo que reproduzca el problema. subilo aca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías probar el siguiente código:

```
ResumenDatosReserva ResumenDatosReserva = new ResumenDatosReserva();

Point pointToWindow = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
Point point = PointToScreen(pointToWindow);

ResumenDatosReserva.Location = point;
                   this.dgvPrestamos.Controls.Add(ResumenDatosReserva);
ResumenDatosReserva.BringToFront();
```

Con esto obtienes la posición actual del mouse.

Comment: Esta me sirvió, muchas gracias!